# Расположение элементов на Jframe

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста с помощью какого Layout можно расположить элементы на Jframe в столбик один под другим? Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `BoxLayout` . `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` задает столбик (по оси Y). Например:

```
package stack;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {
    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        addAButton("Button 1", pane);
        addAButton("Button 2", pane);
        addAButton("Button 3", pane
}

private static void addAButton(String text, Container container) {
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    container.add(button);
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    // Создание фрейма
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("BoxLayoutDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    // запустить приложение
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}